# How to display 2 different containers side by side in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to put the Order Panel and the Order Menu side by side, they are 2 different components (containers). In my css, I've tried display: inline-block and also flex-direction:row. I've tried flex on the parent component (Order), but it reduced the width of both components. It's something very simple, but I'm not able to do it.  Can someone guide me to find the mistake?

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Stack from "@mui/joy/Stack";
import OrderPanel from "./OrderPanel";
import OrderMenu from "./OrderMenu";
import "./Order.css";


function Order()  {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="Order">
          <OrderPanel />
          <OrderMenu/>
      </div>
    </>
  );
  
};

export default Order;

import React from "react";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Stack from "@mui/joy/Stack";
import OrderPanel from "./OrderPanel";
import "./Order.css";


function OrderMenu() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="Order-Menu">
        <Container>Order Menu</Container>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default OrderMenu;


import React from "react";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Stack from "@mui/joy/Stack";
import "./Order.css";
import Order from "./Order";

function OrderPanel() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="Order-Panel">
        <Container>Order Panel</Container>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default OrderPanel;
```

```css
.Order {
    background-color:darkkhaki;
    height: 50%;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.Order-Panel{
    background-color: beige;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    margin-right: 60vw;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 50vh;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: inline-block;
    
}

.Order-Menu{
    background-color: aquamarine;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    margin-left:2vw;
    height:10vw;
    width: 45vh;
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Following mui docs (one approach)

> It is recommended to use the **sx** prop if you are using mui.
> [Mui grid docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/)

By the other hand, to position two containers side by side you can use the `Grid` mui component

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <Item>xs=6</Item>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <Item>xs=6</Item>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Resulting a container
[Resulting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u4oh.png)

> `xs={6}` sets the columns of the grid that `Grid item` can take (`Grid container` has 12 columns by default)